# How to merge passing prop and default prop in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my simple `create-react-app`

I have this incoming prop

```
dummyConfig: {
    prop_1: {
      prop_1_1: "100",
      prop_1_2: "100"
    }
  }
```

in my app's default prop, I have

```
dummyConfig: {
    prop_1: {
      prop_1_1: "prop_1_1",
      prop_1_2: "prop_1_2"
    },
    prop_2: {
      prop_2_1: "prop_2_1",
      prop_2_2: "prop_2_2"
    }
  }
```

I want to have a final prop in App.js to become following, so I can use it.

```
final

dummyConfig: {
    prop_1: {
      prop_1_1: "100",
      prop_1_2: "100"
    },
    prop_2: {
      prop_2_1: "prop_2_1",
      prop_2_2: "prop_2_2"
    }
  }
```

[github link](https://github.com/kenpeter/merge-prop)

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

const dummyConfig = {
  prop_1: {
    prop_1_1: "100",
    prop_1_2: "100"
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App
      // sys
      systemConfig={{ systemConfig: "systemConfig" }}
      // app
      applicationConfig={{ applicationConfig: "applicationConfig" }}
      // dummy
      dummyConfig={dummyConfig}
    />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

function App(props) {
  //test
  console.log("props", props);

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}

App.defaultProps = {
  systemConfig: {},
  applicationConfig: {},
  dummyConfig: {
    prop_1: {
      prop_1_1: "prop_1_1",
      prop_1_2: "prop_1_2"
    },
    prop_2: {
      prop_2_1: "prop_2_1",
      prop_2_2: "prop_2_2"
    }
  }
};

App.propTypes = {
  systemConfig: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  applicationConfig: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default App;
```

When I do console.log I only see. Any way to achieve with using prop and default prop?

```
{
  "systemConfig": {
    "systemConfig": "systemConfig"
  },
  "applicationConfig": {
    "applicationConfig": "applicationConfig"
  },
  "dummyConfig": {
    "prop_1": {
      "prop_1_1": "100",
      "prop_1_2": "100"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving `App` a default props field of `dummyConfig`, you can have a "default value" for `dummyConfig` as a variable inside of your function.

For example:

```
function App(props) {
  //test
  const dummyConfig = {
    prop_1: {
      prop_1_1: "prop_1_1",
      prop_1_2: "prop_1_2"
    },
    prop_2: {
      prop_2_1: "prop_2_1",
      prop_2_2: "prop_2_2"
    },
    ...props.dummyConfig
  }
  // dummyConfig will now be a merge with your props, and "default value"

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}

App.defaultProps = {
  systemConfig: {},
  applicationConfig: {},
  dummyConfig: {}
};

App.propTypes = {
  systemConfig: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  applicationConfig: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

If you want your state to change based on the props that are passed in, you could do something  like:

```
const defaultDummyConfig = {
  prop_1: {
    prop_1_1: "prop_1_1",
    prop_1_2: "prop_1_2"
  },
  prop_2: {
    prop_2_1: "prop_2_1",
    prop_2_2: "prop_2_2"
  },
}

function App(props) {
  //test
  const [ dummyState, setDummyState ] = useState({
    ...defaultDummyConfig,
    ...props.dummyConfig
  });

  // update the new state if the prop ever changes
  // this way, dummyState will always contain what you want (if it's your desired effect)
  useEffect(() => {
    setDummyState({...defaultDummyConfig, props.dummyConfig})
  }, [props.dummyConfig])

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

Comment: for your 1st block of code, is it possible to use App.defaultProps without using const dummyConfig = { xxxxx, ..props.dummyConfig}

Comment: Not that I know of. Typically, you use defaultProps to provide your component with a default value for a prop only if the user doesn't specify one. If the user specifies one, then by default, you would want to completely change the defaultProp. In cases where you don't defaultProps isn't the way you want to implement it since that's not what it's meant to be used as.

Comment: If you think about parameters for functions, if you have a default value for a parameter i.e `function(param1= {...})`, the expected behavior is to replace the default value if a parameter is given. It's the same thing for passing in props to components.

Comment: yes, true, I guess. Will get back to you with this one